# What is an 'action' layer in Adobe Gaming SDK context?

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea, air

I am using IntelliJ and Adobe Gaming SDK (Adobe Air & AS3) to learn how to write a game. In [the tutorial I'm following](http://www.flashgametuts.com/tutorials/as3/how-to-create-a-tower-defense-game-in-as3-part-1/), the author mentions an 'action layer' in an the main `.fla` file. This is about mid-way down the page.

I don't have a `main .fla` file, just `.as` source files. Is there a place for me to put the kind of code to which the author is referring? Here is a snippet:

```
stop();

//setting vars to step in for turns and special blocks
var S:String = 'START';
var F:String = 'FINISH';
var U:String = 'UP';
var R:String = 'RIGHT';
var D:String = 'DOWN';
var L:String = 'LEFT';

var startDir:String;//the direction the enemies go when they enter
var finDir:String;//the direction the enemies go when they exit

// ...and more
```

It appears that as some examples have demonstrated, this is where key mapping/binding would also be added for event handlers, etc.

My question is, since I am not using the Flex SDK, and have a pure ActionScript module, where do I put this type of source?

Comment: The author is probably using flash ide, you are not so you will want to create a document class for that code

Comment: @Boat5: An example of what that might look like would be an acceptable answer. :) Would it be helpful if I attached an image of the project structure in IntelliJ?

Comment: This might be another question, but can I work with `Stage`s, etc. without using Animator CC (creating .fla files, etc)? I'm trying to figure out what the Animator IDE is doing behind the scenes so I can do the same with IntelliJ.

Comment: Im sorry i dont have better detail for you at the moment im not trying to be vague, Ive never used intelliJ only flash ide and flashdevelop. A very general description is that you asign one "main" .as file of your project as the document class. If you dont do this in Flash pro, it will do it for you on compile. Perhaps someone can describe better but for now lookup the document class and it should help explain. Sorry if shitty answer

Comment: Good information @Boat5. It gives me a place to start looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't have a main .fla file, just .as source files.

So does pretty much every development environment (including the Flex SDK) *except* Adobe Flash/Animate.

If a resource mentions layers, it is employing Adobe Flash/Animate as the tool.

The problem is, it provides much more than just layers: there are drawing tools, a library, etc. That's why I would not recommend following that tutorial. It will continue to mention tools and workflows specific to Adobe Flash/Animate, that will not apply to your tools and there might not be a simple substitute.

You wouldn't want to follow this tutorial anyway as it's full of bad practices.

On the website of the Adobe Gaming SDK it is mentioned that it comes with all kinds of examples and resources. I suggest that you checkout those and try to get started with them. It's very hard to find good quality resources for Actionscript (not saying there are none), which is why it's a good idea to stick with the official resources.

> where do I put this type of source?

That depends on what the source is doing. Some of it might go into the constructor of a class, functions might become methods of a class, etc. Object oriented code usually has more structure than the imperative code you see there, which means that there's no 1 to 1 conversion. It takes experience with the language to make a good translation between the two. As you are just starting out, a tutorial based on Adobe Flash/Animate is not the best starting point.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is just typically the layer in the IDE that people put the majority of their code in. It's just a way of organizing stuff. There can be specific reasons to put things in different layers for utility purposes but usually this is more of an organizational technique than anything else. In other words I wouldn't worry about replicating that part too much.

So more to the point, there isn't such a thing as an "actions layer" per se, rather, the author of that tutorial is making a new layer to write some code in and he named the layer "actions" which has been a common method.